# how to get an input text when click link in jquery

Tags: html, click

i'm doing a goto link in web page, with an input text aside it.
the goto link appear both on top and bottom of webpage.

```
<div class="gotopage">
    goto page<input type="text" class="page_i"/>
    <a href="###" class="Goto">Go</a>
</div>
```

in jquery, i need to get text beside link:

```
$('a.Goto').live('click',function(){
    window.location.href = ...;
});
```

how to get text value, it shouldn't be id, for id appear twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get sibling text input:

```
$('a.Goto').live('click',function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).prev('.page_i').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text in a `span` tag:

```
<div class="gotopage">
 <span>goto page</span><input type="text" class="page_i"/>
 <a href="###" class="Goto">Go</a>
</div>
```

Then select it

```
$('a.Goto').live('click',function(){
   window.location.href = $(this).closest('span').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get text of an input box by using this code

```
<script>
$('a.Goto').live('click',function(){
    txt=$('.gotopage .page_i').val();
    alert(txt);
});
</script>
```